# 1.6V SSR power supply regulation

Tags: voltage, led, solid-state-relay, regulations

I am trying to power an SSR opto coupler, and need a maximum 1.6V supply, so that I don't blow the LED. However the main voltage supply is between 0V and 4V, and the minimum zener diode voltage I can find is 1.8V. The regulation needs to be very low current, and not distort the waveform in any way. Any help would be great!
[image: circuit]

SSR Datasheet: https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/307/en-3gvm_ar_dr-1771733.pdf

Comment: 2.2v zener - 0.6v rectifier = 1.6v

Answer (score 0):

Normal practice is to feed the optical input (the LED) via a series dropper resistor. You know it will develop 1.6 volts at 10 mA so, if feeding from a 5 volt signal you want 3.4 volts to drop across the series resistor hence, the resistor should have a resistance of at least: -

$$\dfrac{\text{3.4 volts}}{\text{10 mA}} = \text{340 ohms}$$

To be on the safe side, choose 390 ohms. To be even safer, link the data sheet for the SSR and I'll double-check things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem i have got is that the input voltage to the SSR is not fixed, it will go between 0V and 4V, and there is no fixed voltage, so i dont think i could use a series resistor, as the voltage drop needed would be constantly changing. one way i did look into was to use a zener diode to keep the voltage under 3.3V, and then use a series resistor using 1.7V as the voltage drop, however in all the simulations i have done this has not worked.

Comment: https://www.mouser.co.uk/datasheet/2/307/en-3gvm_ar_dr-1771733.pdf

Comment: @jackv12333 I don't think you have a problem. 30 mA is the maximum you can put into the device and providing you keep below 25 mA worst case you should be fine. This means the resistor should be chosen with 4 volts in mind as the maximum voltage.